# Retrieve Photo as well in Google Business Profile Location

Tags: node.js, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I have the following code to retrieve information about a Business location from the Google My Business API.

```
        let readMask = "storeCode,name,languageCode,title,phoneNumbers,categories,storefrontAddress,websiteUri,regularHours,specialHours,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions,latlng,openInfo,metadata,profile,relationshipData,moreHours";
        let url = `https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/${account.id}/locations?readMask=${readMask}`;
```

What value can I add to the `readMask` field such that the business photo will also be sent along?

Comment: Please specify what is a business photo to you, ideally with a real place example and that photo or screenshots indicating where in the UI you are seeing the photo you are seeking to retrieve.

Comment: I meant the business logo. I was expecting it to be under profile in the response but the profile contains only description

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a list media request (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media/list) and look for the media item that has category PROFILE (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media#MediaItem.Category).

Comment: Imagine the user has a very long list of locations this is not efficient because I have to loop through each location and fetch the media one after the other. This is already leading to timeouts on my client side. Is there no better way out?

Comment: You should be requesting the data before you need it and cache it in that case.